# Building different cultures Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wix, locale

I am trying to build a C# WPF application that uses zh-CN culture aswell as English. Running the project in Visual Studio takes the correct resource file and displays the correct translations however when I build the application .msi, it reverts back to using the default English resource file.

I have explicitly set the CultureInfo to zh-CN but it still made no difference.

Anyone have any ideas on what the issue may be?

Thanks

Comment: How you create the msi? Are the zh-CN resources installed in your application folder when you install the msi?

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen I'm using Visual Studio with a WIX installer, I am actually not seeing the zh-CN resources, is there something I'm missing configuration wise?

Comment: I am not an expert in WiX-Installer, but I maybe you have to include the resource files manually into your msi. There should be subfolders for different languages in your output directory.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen I finally figured it out and yes your are right with the WiX Installer having to add the resource files there also. My other main issue was that I created the resource file manually by coping the English version and hence the output directories were not created automatically by VS